# Simple worker class

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, thread-safety

I just wrote a basic worker class for this person

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827459/assigning-a-new-task-to-a-thread-after-the-thread-completes-in-c

and I wanted to ask if the code has been written properly, it's supposed to have multi-thread support.

Any feedback would be nice.

**[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/ARbq5O)**

```
class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(bool start) : m_Running(start) { if (start) private_start(); }
    Worker() : m_Running(false) { }
    ~Worker() { stop(); }

    template<typename... Args>
    void push_task(Args&&... args)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
            m_Queue.push_back(std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }

        m_Condition.notify_all();
    }

    void start()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
            if (m_Running == true) return;
            m_Running = true;
        }

        private_start();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
            if (m_Running == false) return;
            m_Running = false;
        }

        m_Condition.notify_all();
        m_Thread.join();
    }

private:
    void private_start()
    {
        m_Thread = std::thread([this]
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                decltype(m_Queue) local_queue;
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
                    m_Condition.wait(lk, [&] { return !m_Queue.empty() + !m_Running; });

                    if (!m_Running)
                    {
                        for (auto& func : m_Queue)
                            func();

                        m_Queue.clear();
                        return;
                    }

                    local_queue = std::swap(m_Queue, local_queue);
                }

                for (auto& func : local_queue)
                    func();
            }
        });
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable m_Condition;
    std::list<std::function<void()>> m_Queue;
    std::mutex m_Mutex;
    std::thread m_Thread;
    bool m_Running = false;
};

void do_work(unsigned id)
{
    //static std::mutex cout_mutex;
    //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    {
        Worker workers[3];
        int counter = 0;

        for (auto& worker : workers)
            worker.start();

        for (auto& worker : workers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                worker.push_task(do_work, ++counter + i);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "finish" << std::endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Does moving leave the object in a usable state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930105/does-moving-leave-the-object-in-a-usable-state)

According to this your `m_Queue` object is valid, yet in an unspecified state.
The easiest way to make the state specified again might be calling `m_Queue.clear()` directly after `local_queue = std::move(m_Queue);` or even reinitializing `m_Queue` with new object.

I tried to find out whether just clearing `m_Queue` is sufficient, yet I couldn't find anything definate apart from comments. I think it is at least "more safe" to use than you current approach.

---

For readability reasons I would have also changed the structure of your `private_start` to something like this

```
void private_start()
{
    m_Thread = std::thread([this]
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            decltype(m_Queue) local_queue;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
                m_Condition.wait(lk, [&] { return !m_Queue.empty() + !m_Running; });

                if (!m_Running)
                {
                    for (auto& func : m_Queue)
                        func();

                    m_Queue.clear();
                    return;
                }

                //Move to local
                local_queue = std::move(m_Queue);
                m_Queue.clear();
            }

            //Process local
            for (auto& func : local_queue)
            {
                func();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But that's more of a personnal preference.

---

As a last comment I would recommend updating your example to call `stop` on all workers so your application doesn't end prematurely.

Comment: I have updated my class with std::swap instead of std::move, but I could have used list<T> splice(whole list) instead, as I think the speed is almost the same. Both solutions are one liners and guaranty that m_Queue remains valid. From what I've read clearing m_Queue after moving it properly restores the state of the list, but not one liner tho, neither is reinitializing m_Queue with new object. Also, the destructor already calls stop, which waits (blocks) for the threads to finish. I've taken your advise to changed the structure of private_start